# Div is stuck inside another div

Tags: html, css, position, move

I have a DIV with an H2 inside. The DIV is completely separate from all the other work, placed at the bottom of the HTML, yet for some reason it is sticking to the top of the page, inside one of the other DIVs. I've tried Googling but to no avail, I need it below the background to start working on a new section. What should I be looking at?

https://jsfiddle.net/5vLvm3xx/

ps. I dont know how many people browse these forums, but I've been asking alot of questions here today because I keep running into these small issues that stop me from continuing (im a beginner). I hope it is no bother. :)

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>onepageskiw</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div>
<nav>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Top</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Om Eventet</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lokation</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</div>

<div id="logodiv">
<img src="../design/logotop.png">
</div>

<div id="overskrift">
<h1>EVENTET STARTER OM</h1>
</div>

<div id="countdowner">
<table id="table">
<tr>
<div id="countdown">
<td id="id1"></td>
<td id="id2"></td>
<td id="id3"></td>
<td id="id4"></td>
</div>
<tr>
<tr>
<td class="timeLabel">DAGE</td>
<td class="timeLabel">TIMER</td>
<td class="timeLabel">MIN</td>
<td class="timeLabel">SEK</td>
</tr>
</tr>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<script>
CountDownTimer('06/25/2016 10:00 AM', 'id');

function CountDownTimer(dt, id)
{
    var end = new Date(dt);

    var _second = 1000;
    var _minute = _second * 60;
    var _hour = _minute * 60;
    var _day = _hour * 24;
    var timer;

    function showRemaining() {
        var now = new Date();
        var distance = end - now;
        if (distance < 0) {

            clearInterval(timer);
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';

            return;
        }
        var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

        document.getElementById(id+"1").innerHTML = days;
        document.getElementById(id+"2").innerHTML = hours;
        document.getElementById(id+"3").innerHTML = minutes;
        document.getElementById(id+"4").innerHTML = seconds;
    }

    timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
}
</script>

<div id="information">
<h2>Help me. I'm stuck.</h2>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
@charset "utf-8";

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?    family=Montserrat:400|Raleway:100,400|);

body {
margin:0;
}

html { 
background:url(http://www.freelargeimages.com/wp-        content/uploads/2014/12/Black_background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
background-size: cover;    
background-repeat: no-repeat;
/*background-position: top center;*/
}

#logodiv {
position:relative;
text-align:center;
}

#logodiv>img {
width:15%;

}

h1  {
font-family:raleway;
font-weight:100;
position:absolute;  
width:100%;
text-align:center;
color:white;
letter-spacing:11px;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-230%);
font-size:2.5em;
white-space: nowrap;
}

#countdowner {
font-family:sans-serif;
color:white;
position:absolute;
margin:0;
padding:0;
width:100%;
font-size:2em;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-20%);
}

#id1 {
font-size:2.5em;
}

#id2 {
font-size:2.5em;
}

#id3 {
font-size:2.5em;
}

#id4 {
font-size:2.5em;
}

.timeLabel {
font-size:0.7em;
color:#f1a01e;
font-family:montserrat;
font-weight:700;
}

#table {
margin:0 auto;
text-align:center;
}

#table td{
padding:0px 45px;
}

#menu {
position:absolute;
padding:0;
width:100%;
bottom:0;
text-align:center;
}

#menu>li {
font-size:20px;
list-style:none;
display:inline-block;
text-transform:uppercase;
letter-spacing:3px;
font-family:raleway;
font-weight:400;
}

#menu>li>a {
padding:0 15px;
text-decoration:none;
color:white;
}

#menu>li>a:hover {
color:#f1a01e;
}

#information {
position:relative;  
clear:both;
color:red;
}
```

Comment: That's because all the other elements are placed absolute... which makes them 'flow' above the body.

Comment: But I've had to do this for them to work properly in regards to centerizing and placements, unless I've done it a wrong/complicated way? Like I've wrote I'm still a beginner. I tried changing some to relative but then the elements start jumping all about the page.

Answer (score 0):

This is because all of your other elements are using `position: absolute;`

Comment: Changing them all to relative (or removing them) gives me a mess of a result, and the text still appears to be stuck inside the DIV: https://jsfiddle.net/5vLvm3xx/1/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In your updated fiddle `#information` is not contained in any other `<div>` so I'm not understanding the problem.  If you wanted to revert to absolute positioning, wrap all of the other code in a `<div>` and then place `#information` below it.

Comment: I may be totally missing something here then because the text is still "on top" of the background. Why is it not below it, separate from the background? I looked at the CSS of the background image but removing any properties doesn't seem to do anything for me.

Also Googled "wrapping" but I cant seem to find a relevant code for it? I put a DIV around all content (except the DIV with the red text). What am I supposed to do with this DIV "wrapping" around it all?

Comment: That text will always appear on top of the background because you have the background image applied to `<html>`.  Everything in your document is a child of `<html>` so they will always appear above it.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the flex properties, height order and rearrange a bit the structure (1 wrapper and a class): https://jsfiddle.net/5vLvm3xx/2/

```js
CountDownTimer('06/25/2016 10:00 AM', 'id');

function CountDownTimer(dt, id) {
  var end = new Date(dt);

  var _second = 1000;
  var _minute = _second * 60;
  var _hour = _minute * 60;
  var _day = _hour * 24;
  var timer;

  function showRemaining() {
    var now = new Date();
    var distance = end - now;
    if (distance < 0) {

      clearInterval(timer);
      document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';

      return;
    }
    var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

    document.getElementById(id + "1").innerHTML = days;
    document.getElementById(id + "2").innerHTML = hours;
    document.getElementById(id + "3").innerHTML = minutes;
    document.getElementById(id + "4").innerHTML = seconds;
  }

  timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
}
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400|Raleway:100,400|);
 body {
  margin: 0;
}
html {
 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /*background-position: top center;*/
}
#logodiv {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
#logodiv>img {
  width: 15%;
}
h1 {
  font-family: raleway;
  font-weight: 100;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 11px;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#countdowner {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 2em;
}
#id1 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
}
#id2 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
}
#id3 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
}
#id4 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
}
.timeLabel {
  font-size: 0.7em;
  color: #f1a01e;
  font-family: montserrat;
  font-weight: 700;
}
#table {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
#table td {
  padding: 0px 45px;
}
#menu {
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#menu>li {
  font-size: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-family: raleway;
  font-weight: 400;
}
#menu>li>a {
  padding: 0 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
#menu>li>a:hover {
  color: #f1a01e;
}
#information {
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
  color: red;
}
html,
body,
.splash {
  height: 100%;
}
.splash {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  min-height:450px; background: url(http://www.freelargeimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Black_background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
.splash>* {
  order: -1;
  flex: 1;
}
.splash:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  order: 0;
  flex: 1;
}
.menu {
  order: 1;
  flex: none;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="splash">


  <div class="menu">
    <nav>
      <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Top</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Om Eventet</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Lokation</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <div id="logodiv">
    <img src="../design/logotop.png">
  </div>

  <div id="overskrift">
    <h1>EVENTET STARTER OM</h1>
  </div>

  <div id="countdowner">
    <table id="table">
      <tr>
        <div id="countdown">
          <td id="id1"></td>
          <td id="id2"></td>
          <td id="id3"></td>
          <td id="id4"></td>
        </div>
        <tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="timeLabel">DAGE</td>
            <td class="timeLabel">TIMER</td>
            <td class="timeLabel">MIN</td>
            <td class="timeLabel">SEK</td>
          </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

</div>

<div id="information">
  <h2>Help me. I'm stuck.</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Im afraid I do not know squad about flex properties, it is something I have to look up. But your solution does seem to do the trick. But why is the text still on top of the background image? What did I miss?

Comment: @ThorKousted no problem for the flex properties, best is to read definitions and tutorials while playing around with it using http://codepen.io/pen (see in lve your html/css code) it takes a while to be familiar with display and positionning, do not worry if you do not get it at first. for the text and image, i think i did miss something cause i do not see what you talk about :)

Comment: What you "missed" (or I explained badly is most likely :P) is that the background is repeating as I make new DIVs. As you can see the background is still behind the red text: http://prntscr.com/b96woh - I need the background to stop repeating/showing after the <a href...> links, so that I can start using new backgrounds behind the red text. Does it make sense?

Comment: @ThorKousted  okay, so you just need to move the background to the first container (with class spash in the snippet :) )  https://jsfiddle.net/5vLvm3xx/5/